# getting infinite loop when loading images via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to make user uploaded files private in node.js. And I'm using angular to serve the file in the client side.

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <div class="details" ng-if="message.type == 'photo'">
    <img ng-src="{{ chat_ctrl.getPhoto(message.photo, message.conversation_id, message.type) }}"  class="message-photo" alt="{{ message.text }}">
    <p>{{ message.text }}</p>
    <small am-time-ago="message.timestamp" am-preprocess="unix"></small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the function I'm using to get the file.

```
    me.getPhoto = function(url, id, message_type){

        if(message_type == 'photo'){            
            RequestsService.getPhoto(url, id).then(function(response){
               console.log(response); //returns the data-uri of the image
               return response;
            });
        }else{
            return '';
        }

    };
```

The function calls the `getPhoto` method from the `RequestService` which makes the request to the node.js server:

```
    function getPhoto(url, id){

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var request = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: base_url + '/uploads' + url,
            params: {'url': url, 'id' : id}
        };

        $http(request)
            .success(function(response){
                $timeout.cancel(me.timer);
                deferred.resolve(response);
            })
            .error(function(data){
                deferred.reject();  
            });

        me.requestTimeout(deferred);

        return deferred.promise;        

    };
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

The server returns the data-uri representing the image. I already tried using `ng-click` to call the same method and its returning the data uri fine:

```
<img src="" ng-click="chat_ctrl.getPhoto(message.photo, message.conversation_id, message.type)"  class="message-photo" alt="{{ message.text }}">
```

Any ideas?

**update**

I tried returning the data I'm getting from the http request directly but I still get the same error.

```
$http(request)
            .success(function(response){
                //$timeout.cancel(me.timer);
                //deferred.resolve(response);
                return response;
            })
            .error(function(data){
                return data;
                //deferred.reject();    
            });
```

Comment: try to keep the returned url in $scope/controller instance rather returning a promise and see if working or not then we can narrow down the cause

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using async function calls in `ng-src`. The expression in `ng-src` is executed on every `digest`.

Try loading all photos in the controller first:

```
loadPhotos();

loadPhotos = function() {
    for(var i=0,max=messages.length; i<max; i++) {
        me.getPhoto(i);
    }
};

getPhoto = function(index){
    if(messages[index].message_type == 'photo'){            
        RequestsService
            .getPhoto(messages[index].photo, messages[index].conversation_id)
            .then(function(response){
                messages[index].photoSrc = response;
            });
    }
};
```

In your template use:

```
<img ng-src="{{message.photoSrc}}" ... />
```